# Are you going to my house? or Are you coming to my house? Do we care about the real location when saying?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, now A & B are talking via telephone

**Case 1**: A is currently at A's house & B is currently at B's house.

A: Are you coming to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am coming to your house tonight.

No problem with case 1, everyone agrees to say like that

**Case 2**: A is currently at a supermarket & B is currently at B's house.

A: Are you coming to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am coming to your house tonight.

or

A: Are you going to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am going to your house tonight.

How to say in case 2?

**Case 3**: A is currently at an A's neighbor (the next door to A)  & B is currently at B's house.

A: Are you coming to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am coming to your house tonight.

or

A: Are you going to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am going to your house tonight.

How to say in case 3?

**Case 4**: A & B are currently at B's house.

A: Are you coming to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am coming to your house tonight.

or

A: Are you going to my house tonight?

B: Yes, I am going to your house tonight.

How to say in case 4?

In general, **Do we care about the real location of the speaker to select the right word "come" & "go"?**

Comment: Remove the word "staying" from each of your cases. It is confusing because to "stay" at someone's house is to be sleeping there, not necessarily to be there at the moment.   CORRECT: "A is currently at A's house & B is currently at B's house."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an addition to your [earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/97033/2992), so let me answer with an addition to my [earlier answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/97037/2992).

When the coming or going does not take place in the present time, the choice to *come* or to *go* depends on the situation at the time the action happens.

So, in your **case 2**:
If A expects to be home to receive B, he'll ask if B will *come* to his place.

On the other hand, if A is on holiday, and has asked B to drop by his place to feed the cat, he would probably ask if B will *go* to his house tonight.

**Case 3** is essentially not different from case 2. If A expects to be home to receive B, he'll ask if B will come.

And the same goes for **case 4**. It doesn't matter where A and B are at present if they discuss the future.

The same goes for the past. If A asks B why he didn't *come* to C's part last week, we can assume A was at the party. However, if A asks B why he didn't *go* to C's party, A was not at the party either (but maybe had expected B to go there).

---

To answer your question in your comment elsewhere: *But let say A & B in A's house & B said "We should go to my house" & then 30 mins later A & B are at B's house. They both meet at B's house. How can you explain that?*.

Both A&B will *move away* from where they are - and away from where they are having their conversation; hence, they *go* to B's house.

Interestingly, if A and B are at A's house, B might say:
*I'm going to my house now. Will you come to my house later?*

Again, B wil move *away* from where they both are now, but later, A will move *towards* B, so A will come to B.

Overall, I really think you may be looking too deeply into this. *Coming* and *going* are generally *opposites* and usually intuition tells us which of two opposites we should use. Trying to narrow down the details of every possible use case seems to lead to more confusion than necessary. Try to roughly imagine that *coming = arriving* and *going = leaving*.

After the edit: **Do we care about the real location of the speaker to select the right word "come" & "go"?**

Yes, we do. If the speaker is talking about an action that will bring him and the listener closer together *at the moment the action did, does or will take place*, the speaker will generally use *come*. Otherwise they'll use *go*.

Answer (score 2):

In the situations describing movement between the speaker and the listener to the place where one of them will be present at the appointed time, the verb *come* is used.

The verb *go* is used to talk about the movement from where the speaker or listener is *to another place*.

All your situations suggest that the speaker A will be at home when the speaker B arrives, so the verb *come* should be used in every situation.

The source: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/come-or-go).

In general, in choosing between *come* and *go*, the location of the speaker and the listener at the point of their future meeting (at one of their places or anywhere else) is crucial; the place (location) where they are discussing that, doesn't seem to be of any importance.

Comment: CHeck this video http://youglish.com/search/%22come%20to%20my%20house%22, they used a lot of  "come to my house" but they were not at their houses at the tim e they were talking

Comment: But let say A & B in A's house & B said "We should go to my house" & then 30 mins later A & B are at B's house. They both meet at B's house. How can you explain that?

Comment: They're both relocating the place of their interaction: they are leaving A's house and going to B's house, but before that, B came to A's and afterwards, when they are at B's, his mum might ask: Who's come with you?